# Connect to SQL Server Express database via HTTP handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-express, httphandler

I am trying to update the table in the database each time the file is downloaded. The database is the "DefaultConnection(WebsiteName)" that was created when I used the sample website template. It is the database that stores all the registered users. I have added this table to that database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Download] (
    [filename] NVARCHAR(50) NULL  , 
    [counter] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , 
);
```

I created a HTTP Handler that gets fired when I click download and is working without the SQL connection part:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Download" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public class Download : IHttpHandler {

    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;

        private string FilesPath
        {
            get
            {
                return @"path to directory holding files";
            }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string fileName = context.Request.QueryString["filename"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) && File.Exists(FilesPath + fileName))
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
                context.Response.WriteFile(FilesPath + fileName);

                //connect to the db

                conn = new SqlConnection(
                "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-websiteName-20130405020152;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-websiteName-20130405020152‌​.mdf");
                //the sql command to increment counter by 1
                cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE counter SET counter = counter+1 WHERE filename=@filename", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", "Default");

                using (conn)
                {
                    //open the connection
                    conn.Open();
                    //send the query
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write(FilesPath + fileName + " Invalid filename");
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable {
            get {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I cannot get it to connect with any connection strings I can find. I have tried the one that is shown in the "web.config". It will always try to connect for a while, but then throws an exception on the `conn.Open();` line saying it couldn't connect:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) .

My main question is, how do I connect to this default database so that I can update the information in this table when the file is downloaded.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: @usr With the connection string I can see by right-clicking -> Properties: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to connect to it finally using this:

```
conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no attached db file name in your connection string. Please get the connection string for local db from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: Sorry in the OP that was just one of the last attempts. Like I stated I have tried to use the connection string given in the "web.config" and I still get the same error. I cannot quite grasp that link either, sorry.

Comment: Links is working fine for me. I would be interested to see your connection string in web.config.

Comment: I mean I cannot quite unsterstand the information provided in that link. Connection string in "web.config" is: "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-websiteName-20130405020152;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-websiteName-20130405020152.mdf" And the one I can see by right-clicking -> Properties is: "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\userName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\websiteName\App_Data\aspnet-websiteName-20130405020152.mdf";Initial Catalog=aspnet-websiteName-20130405020152;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Do u have the database file in your app_data folder. If you have the file I don't see problem why would not you be able to connect to the database using web.config connection string.

Comment: Yes the file is there in the app_data folder, I have checked already.

Comment: "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-websiteName-20130405020152;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-websiteName-20130405020152‌​.mdf" could you please try to follow this convention of connection string than yours. Specailly the SSPI for integrated security and use data directory to pick up the website app_data foler path.

Comment: With that string I get: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 139.